# Can else if statements be navigated through in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

We can navigate through methods using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, Is there a similar shortcut to navigate through if else if blocks, if not what other IDEs have this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut specific to if/else blocks. The closest available actions are "Move caret to code block start" (Ctrl-[) and "Move caret to code block end" (Ctrl-]).

Comment: The Navigate menu in android-studio 2.1.1 is missing this action.